# Issue while addding files in IPFS server having cloudflare enabled

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cloudflare, ipfs

I have a ubuntu server having cloudflare enabled in it. I have set up the nginx for reverse proxy, I have defined the ports and done IPFS setup.

While adding the file on the server I am getting the error that says:
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I am creating a buffer of a file and adding the data using `ipfs.files.add function`.
Here is the code snippet:

```
let testBuffer = new Buffer(testFile); 
ipfs.files.add(testBuffer, function (err, file) { 
  if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
        res.send(responseGenerator.getResponse(500, "Failed to process your request!!!", [])); 
  }
  console.log(file) 
}
```

Kindly help with the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the json that is causing the problem?

Comment: I am creating a buffer of a file and adding the data using ipfs.files.add function.

Here is the code snippet:

let testBuffer = new Buffer(testFile);

ipfs.files.add(testBuffer, function (err, file) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.send(responseGenerator.getResponse(500, "Failed to process your request!!!", []));
                            }
                            console.log(file)

Comment: I am following the below tutorial
https://hackernoon.com/public-ipfs-node-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-5682747f174b

Comment: So what is in the testFile? Looks like a parsing error

Comment: without nginx can we use https for ipfs?